# Is the [attributes] tag appropriate for GCC __attribute__'s?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

I've seen several questions concerning GCC's `__attribute__`s tagged with [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributes).  That tag is described as

> The attributes tag should be used for any issues relating to a property of an object, element, or file, etc.

The use of this tag in such questions seems unclear at best.

Would a new tag (e.g., `gcc-attributes`) be more appropriate, especially considering the [suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284992/no-need-to-pay-attribute) that the [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributes) tag be deleted?

Comment: the use of the attributes tag in general seems "unclear at best"

Comment: I propose a better title: Is the [attribute] tag appropriate f̶o̶r̶ ̶G̶C̶C̶ ̶_̶_̶a̶t̶t̶r̶i̶b̶u̶t̶e̶_̶_̶'̶s̶?̶

Comment: Can we not create a tag for every keyword. The [tag:declspec] tag is already rather unnecessary and has no usage guidance.

Comment: @vandench sadly, this choir isn't very receptive to that preaching.

Comment: Why is the [[tag:declspec]] tag "rather unnecessary"? It seems like a great tag to me. It lacks usage guidance because no one has submitted it yet. That doesn't make it a bad tag. Heck, most of the good tags have terrible usage guidance, often plagiarized from various sources on the web. You don't judge usefulness or suitability of a tag based on whether someone has submitted an excerpt. The usage guidance for that one is actually kinda obvious (as with most tags). It's for programming questions about the usage of the declspec annotation. Did you really need to see that written?

Comment: The reason I think it is unnecessary is that the majority are already related to [tag:dllexport] and [tag:dllimport] (44/67). That's followed up by several about alignment, which is equivalent to [tag:alignas]. There are a few about *uuid*, *property*, *thread* ([tag:thread-local-storage]), *novtable*, and *nothrow* ([tag:noexcept]). With the remainder mostly being mistagged. I'd be more in favor of your suggestion of just also tagging [tag:attributes] as that is an apt descriptor for most C/C++ compilers as well as C++11.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for clarifying, @vandench. That logic makes much more sense to me. Although it also reveals that it's not really the tag itself that you think is pointless. Possibly, yes, dllexport, dllimport, and declspec could/should be merged together (definitely the first two). Legacy MSVC compiler-specific annotations didn't use the "attribute" terminology, so that makes it much less discoverable, and I would also hesitate to mix in all of the MSVC-specific stuff with either GCC-specific stuff or new C11/C++11 standard attributes.

Comment: The reason I grouped all of them together is that Clang actually treats all of them the same way. There are some minor differences in parsing, such that a `__declspec` won't work on linux, but after the initial parse they're all interacted with the same way in the AST. Though I can absolutely respect that most people might not realize that they're pretty much all the same construct.

Comment: Is a recursive pun lurking somewhere?

Comment: Before considering if [attributes] is appropriate in an specific context, the first question is if [attributes] is appropriate at all. The answer is no. It's way too generic. Anything can have attributes after all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tag [attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attribute) doesn't seem to add anything meaningful to such a question. You might as well just tag it [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) and that will be enough.

There is however a tag [function-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-attributes) which appears to be created specifically for the purpose of gcc attributes. The only problem is that gcc also uses `__attribute__` for variables and no tag for variable attributes exists.

So if any tag should be created, it should be a corresponding [variable-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-attributes) and the tag wiki for the two tags needs to be written. Though I think [gcc-function-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc-function-attributes)  and [gcc-variable-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc-variable-attributes) would be less ambiguous names.

Sources to use in this case would be the friendly manual, found here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Attributes.html
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html

Comment: I'm not sure collecting all GNU C `__attribute__`s under one tag is even useful.  Or grouping variable and function separately.  Variable/type attributes like `__attribute__((packed))` on a struct is unrelated to `__attribute__((section (".text")))`, `weak`, or `__attribute__((visibility ("hidden")))` or other linker stuff, vs. `__attribute__((vector_size(16)))` for SIMD, and those are all variable attributes except visibility.  Attributes that go together (relevant for the same problem) might be both variable and function, e.g. ones like ELF hidden visibility for shared libs.

Comment: But if we do want a tag for it, I think if someone is going to be an expert in GCC attributes in general, they wouldn't make a distinction between function and variable, so probably better to collect them together.  Also, question volume is low enough that we probably only want one tag for all GNU C `__attribute__` things, not trying to subdivide.

Comment: It's only useful for helping future searchers find stuff if it's consistently tagged on all questions where it might be relevant, and there's a 5 tag limit, so only needing one tag is better.  For folks to find new questions to answer, again grouping is also fine.  (And having a specific tag does help with that, since you can watch for new questions in a bunch of tags more easily than `[x] or [y] or ([gcc][attributes])` if that even works to avoid pulling in the millions of [attributes] questions.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using the tag [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributes) to refer to attributes in GCC is valid usage.

We don't need a [gcc-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc-attributes) tag because questions can have multiple tags: [gcc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gcc) [attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributes).

Comment: Isn’t it an ambiguous / context-dependent tag in that usage? The meaning of `attributes` depending on the other tags: `gcc` + `attributes` is very different from `file` + `attributes` or `class` + ` attributes`, etc. I get the feeling this fails [tag removal tests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071) #4 and (partly?) #1

Comment: @Cimbali: Indeed, [c][attributes] finds some questions about GCC attributes, some about file attributes.  So perhaps unlike [Should \[local-functions\] be a synonym of \[nested-function\], or do C# local functions warrant a separate tag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/419841), we don't have a situation where using two tags can reliably disambiguate. However, traffic is low enough that we're probably fine.    Also, the other usages of the [attributes] tag are less similar in meaning, so a hypothetical gold badge in the tag might be even less meaningful than usual.

Comment: Another problem is that GCC isn't the only compiler supporting the GNU dialect of C and C++.  Clang and ICC support most of the same `__attribute__((noreturn))`, `__attribute__((const))`, `__attribute__((section(".text")))`, `__attribute__((target("avx")))` and so on.  But if we made a [gnu-c-attributes] tag, IDK if many people would find it.  Again being low traffic means we don't need to solve the problem.  79 questions tagged [attributes] [c], vs. [12,556 questions tagged \[attributes\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributes) so it's a tiny corner of the tag.

Comment: (80 questions tagged [attributes][gcc]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/attributes+gcc)

Comment: We should either expand the [tag:function-attributes] tag I just found, or if following the advise by this answer, burn it. I personally don't think [tag:attributes] is a good tag for any purpose.